# Timespan type cannot be mapped correctly when using Servicestack CsvSerializer

Tags: csv, asp.net-core, servicestack, timespan

I am trying to convert list of objects to comma seperated string through SerializeToCsv method of Servicestack. However, i realized that timespan cannot be converted correctly. Forexample, my timespan value is 19:00:00, however it converts as PT19H. You can see the code below. I can convert timespan to string by adding string property and change timespan to string at runtime in object, however i thought that there would be better way in Servicestack and could not find anything on internet. Thanks in advance!

```
 public string Convert()
  {
        var data =  _table.Get();
        CsvSerializer.UseEncoding = PclExport.Instance.GetUTF8Encoding(true);
        var csvStr = CsvSerializer.SerializeToCsv(data);

        return csvStr;
  }
```

Comment: If you state "cannot be converted correctly", what do you expect instead?

Comment: Hi Nico, for example for integer or datetime, it converts the same value as text. For timestamp 11:00:00, i expect 11:00:00 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default serialization of TimeSpan which uses the [XSD duration format](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_duration.html), e.g. 19 hours = `PT19H`, i.e. a Period of 19 Hours.

You can change the serialization format with:

```
JsConfig.TimeSpanHandler = TimeSpanHandler.StandardFormat;
```